# Android-NavigationView from right to left

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, gravity

I'm using The last version of Android Studio (1.5) and I want to make a menu using Drawer Layout, for position its call GravityCompat.

I'm trying to use this components and modify it, putting the Drawer out from right to left. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    return true;
}
}
```

The XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout   
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

As you can see, GravityCompat don't let me to put right instead of END or START, and if I put it in the XML, it crash.

with the next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
```

Comment: what is the message on the logcat?

Comment: What is your whole xml layout?

Comment: by the way, the end means from right to left

Comment: I edit with the error from log

Comment: That's the simplest solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/26263009/2591970

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all replace on DrawerLayout the `tools:openDrawer="start"` with `tools:openDrawer="end"`. Now your problem is on the toggle, which opens the left drawer, and because you have only right drawer it throws the exception. You can add your own button on the actionbar (on the right side) to open the drawer. To do that change your *app_bar.xml* like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_button"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:clickable="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_drawer" />
                </FrameLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then change your onCreate method from your Activity like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    findViewById(R.id.drawer_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // open right drawer
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    });

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Also you can find the image for your drawer [here](http://www.google.com/design/icons/) or [here](https://materialdesignicons.com/).
I hope this will help you. :)

Comment: it says the same error, and when I try to put LEFT or RIGHT in the XML it does not recognize me only start, or end.

Comment: about left and right I told you that END is similar to right.

Comment: please write the whole xml file

Comment: you already did, sorry I didn't see that. replace on _DrawerLayout_ the `tools:openDrawer="start"` with `tools:openDrawer="end"`

Comment: mmm, not, it crash :(

Comment: what did the logcat say?

Comment: In the preview looks good but in runtime:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Comment: when did it thrown this exception? When you open or when you close the drawer?

Comment: It hapenned when I open the menu

Answer (score 5):

use a custom drawerLayout just like this :

```
public class TaskManagerDrawerLayout  extends DrawerLayout {

public TaskManagerDrawerLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public TaskManagerDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public TaskManagerDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    try {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void closeDrawer(int gravity) {
    super.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
}

@Override
public void openDrawer(int gravity) {
    super.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
}

}
```

Comment: This did the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing left side navigation drawer change the following properties.

```
tools:openDrawer="start" in DrawerLayout
android:layout_gravity="end" in NavigationView  
toolbar.setNavigationIcon (R.color.transparent); mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled (false);

toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () { @Override public void onClick(View view) { if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen (Gravity.END)) { mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer (Gravity.END); } else { mDrawerLayout.openDrawer (Gravity.END); } } });
```